# Convert each row in tibble into column header

Tags: r, tibble

I'm trying to convert all row in the first column into variables. Which I can call them later by using $ notation (e.g. `data$SWEAT_index`). At this point the variable names were long, I will simplified it later by adding additional column. Maybe my approach are to straightforward. How to deal with this tibble?

```
indices
# A tibble: 30 x 2
   Station                                 Value      
   <chr>                                   <chr>      
 1 Station identifier                      WMKC       
 2 Station number                          48615      
 3 Observation time                        190120/1200
 4 Station latitude                        6.16       
 5 Station longitude                       102.28     
 6 Station elevation                       5.0        
 7 Showalter index                         1.26       
 8 Lifted index                            -2.86      
 9 LIFT computed using virtual temperature -3.38      
10 SWEAT index                             187.99     
# ... with 20 more rows


data <- indices[-1,]
colnames(data) <-data[,1]
data
# A tibble: 29 x 2
   `c("Station number", "Observation time", "Station latitude", "Statio~ `c(48615, NA, 6.16, 102.28~
   <chr>                                                                                       <dbl>
 1 Station number                                                                           48615   
 2 Observation time                                                                            NA   
 3 Station latitude                                                                             6.16
 4 Station longitude                                                                          102.  
 5 Station elevation                                                                            5   
 6 Showalter index                                                                              1.26
 7 Lifted index                                                                                -2.86
 8 LIFT computed using virtual temperature                                                     -3.38
 9 SWEAT index                                                                                188.  
10 K index                                                                                     14.4 
# ... with 19 more rows

dput(indices)
structure(list(Station = c("Station identifier", "Station number", 
"Observation time", "Station latitude", "Station longitude", 
"Station elevation", "Showalter index", "Lifted index", "LIFT computed using virtual temperature", 
"SWEAT index", "K index", "Cross totals index", "Vertical totals index", 
"Totals totals index", "Convective Available Potential Energy", 
"CAPE using virtual temperature", "Convective Inhibition", "CINS using virtual temperature", 
"Equilibrum Level", "Equilibrum Level using virtual temperature", 
"Level of Free Convection", "LFCT using virtual temperature", 
"Bulk Richardson Number", "Bulk Richardson Number using CAPV", 
"Temp [K] of the Lifted Condensation Level", "Pres [hPa] of the Lifted Condensation Level", 
"Mean mixed layer potential temperature", "Mean mixed layer mixing ratio", 
"1000 hPa to 500 hPa thickness", "Precipitable water [mm] for entire sounding"
), Value = c(NA, 48615, NA, 6.16, 102.28, 5, 1.26, -2.86, -3.38, 
187.99, 14.4, 19, 23.9, 42.9, 409.13, 595.76, -26.9, -8.6, 228.72, 
226.79, 819.49, 871.25, 240, 349.48, 294.55, 938.33, 299.97, 
17.45, 5782, 46.56)), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: `?spread` perhaps?

Comment: @RonakShah, added in question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using variable value as column name in data.frame or cbind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15710538/using-variable-value-as-column-name-in-data-frame-or-cbind)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @NelsonGon mentioned we can use `spread`

```
new_df <- tidyr::spread(indices, Station, Value)
```

Now you can call individual values like `` new_df$`Station number ``, `` new_df$`Station identifier `` and so on.

---

In base R, you could transpose, convert it to dataframe and then assign column names using `setNames`

```
new_df <- setNames(data.frame(t(indices$Value)), indices$Station)
```

However, as @Konrad Rudolph mentions transposing the dataframe can mess up the data types of objects so handle it with care.

Comment: Transposition unfortunately messes up the data types. This might still be an OK solution but a `spread` is probably better.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks, updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @RonakShah, how could I prevent the spread() from convert number from `dbl` into `chr` ?  it turns out that way when I incorporate this into API loop. You may check the code here (https://stackoverflow.com/q/54460501/7356308)..

Answer (score 0):

`tidyr::pivot_wider()` is the better option to use currently due to more features etc. See `?spread`.

Using a consistent approach, such as through the meta package `tidyverse`, can lead to more consistent code.

```
data<-
 indices %>%
 tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = Station,
                    values_from = Value)
```